# Java reflection "blindly" getting values

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I am trying to get values from classes by reflection.

The thing is that I don't always know what Type to cast the value.

Is there a way of knowing?

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile-time, then what good would casting do? You can't assign it to appropriate variables anyway. You can use `object.getClass()` to find out the class of any given object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`field.getType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29)

Answer (score 4):

Cast it to `java.lang.Object` IMO

Answer (score 1):

You could get the type of the value that is returned, which might be usefull if you might have different types of values assigned to let's say a field that has an interface/superclass type.

Additionally, you might want to look into [`java.beans.Introspector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) which would return field descriptors along with the getters and setters. Note that this only works if the introspected class complies with the Java Beans conventions.